# Why Can't I Delete a Darksiders Save File? (PC)

Tags: pc, darksiders

Every time I press "continue" from the start menu of Darksiders, no matter how many times I quick saved in the session before, it always starts me reasonably, but not exactly close to where I was when I quicksaved. Also, there's one save file I can't delete with a blue icon on it. Anyone else have this?

Comment: Hi Henry, and welcome to Arqade! It seems like you're asking two questions in one post; here on Arqade, we prefer to have just one main question per post. Could you separate your questions, or just eliminate one altogether?

Comment: Darksiders is saving with checkpoints. The delete thing is probably the autosave which the game overrides and can't do without.

Answer (score 1):

Efc Seany has already answered the first part: you're returned to the last checkpoint, but all your previous actions are remembered (so if you opened a chest, you go back to the checkpoint but the chest is still marked as opened).

For the second part, the save with the blue icon is the auto-save. You cannot delete it or overwrite it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Darksider's Saves are done through Checkpoints. Quick-saving will place you as close to the checkpoint as possible, whilst retaining your quick-save position.

As for the save file - Is this encrypted?